# How to access an Entity in View

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form which has an `User` entity item.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('user', 'entity', array(/* ... */));
}
```

I'd like to access the entity's methods in my template. For example, in a User List where admin can select some users, who are not admin, and remove them from database:

```
{% block body %}
{% for user in form.user %}
    {% if user.isAdmin %}
        {# Disable the checkbox #}
    {% else %}
        {# Render normally #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, when I run my application, Symfony tells me that this method `isAdmin` doesn't exist for object `Symfony\Component\Form\FormView`.

I haven't been able to find any solution (tried using `user.vars.value`). Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I'm using Symfony 2.4.2 .

Comment: what about user[0].isAdmin, user[1].isAdmin?

Comment: what is your version of symfony?

Comment: @repincln No, it didn't work.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli Be patient, I'm trying your solution ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pass users to your view.
Just create a UsersType with multiple choices enabled and do what you want to do on submit.
The following code has not been tested.

```
class UsersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
            'required'      => false,
            'class'         => 'MeMyBundle:UserEntity',
            'property'      => 'id',
            'property_path' => '[id]', # in square brackets!
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true
        ));
    }
}
```

Create your controller action

```
/**
 * @Route("/my_users", name="_users")
 * @Template()
 */
public function usersAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $users = $this->get('my_user_manager')->findAll() //get all users. Fit this line depending on your app.
    $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $users); // I assume you have a UsersType here.

    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        foreach ($data['users'] as $user) {
            // Do what you want with $user, it contains one selected user
        }
        //you can redirect here
    }

    return array(
        'users' => $users,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Now in your view, you can select your users :

```
{% block body %}
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        ...
        <input type="submit" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% else %}
        {# Render a list #}
        <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li>{{user.username}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to query twice for all users (once in the form builder and once in your controller logic) and in case you have a more complex query you have to sustain code at multiple locations.

Comment: Your solution works, but as @ferdynator mentioned, it queries twice for all users. I'll mark this as answer for now until there's a better answer.

Comment: You do not have to query twice for all users. When you have your `users` variable, just build your form with it and pass users and form to your view. I modify my code

Comment: @FlorentMorselli But the `user` is in a `FormType`, which includes other fields (The example in the question is not my real scenario).

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: This solution will not display a list of checkboxes where only the *admins* are checked already. I think the template is still incorrect

Comment: So you should not use a form type, but just create your form in the view add get submitted value in our controller.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli wait, I actually think your revision 3 is the better answer. Sorry, my question was a bit ambiguous: the list is accessible by admin only, but the purpose of the list is to allow admin to remove some users who are not admin.

Comment: And the main reason I want to call `isAdmin` in View is to render a `user` who is an admin differently.

Comment: In fact, I think you should separate admin actions and common users actions. It will prevent security issues and is better to maintain.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli Wait, what? I'm not sure if I'm confused or you're confused. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go for this is a [Custom Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). So in your current form use this:

```
$builder->add('user', 'user', array(/* ... */));
```

And create your own `UserType`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ... implement your logic...
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
       // here you can set the isAdmin value
       // $view->vars['is_admin']
       // you can access your data via $form->getData()
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Now you can create your own template based on that:

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block user_widget %}
    {# This will check a value when the user is admin: #}
    {% set is_selected is_admin %}
    {# let the original widget do the rest: #}
    {{ block('choice_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Also make sure to add this to your `config.yml`

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Comment: Sorry I'm knocking off now and therefore don't have time to test your solution out, just a quick question: Do I really have to create the `user_widget`?

Comment: Just wanted to add an alternative approach. No you don't need to. Since the `user_widget` extends the `choice_widget` there still would be a valid output. But since you override the `is_selected` attribute in the custom template it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer (not tested):

```
/**
 * @Route("/my_users", name="_users")
 * @Template()
 */
public function usersAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $users = $this->get('my_user_manager')->findAll() //get all users. Fit this line depending on your app.

    if ("POST" === $request->getMethod()) {
        $data = $request->request->get('users');
        //Do what you want with submitted data
    }

    return array(
        'users' => $users,
    );
}
```

Your view:

```
{% block body %}
<form action="{{ path("_users") }}" method="post">
    <table>
       <caption>Users</caption>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
             <th>Is admin?</th>
             {% endif %}
             <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
             <td>
                 <input class="{% if user.isAdmin() %}admin{% else %}notadmin{% endif %}" type="checkbox" id="user_{{user.getId()}}" name="users[]" value="{{user.getId()}}"{% if user.isAdmin() %} checked{% endif %} />
             </td>
             {% endif %}
             <td>{{user.getUsername()}}</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```